# VScode gives error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, vscode-debugger

I cannot compile or run a C++ file using VScode but i can do it in the terminal by using g++. When I try to run in VScode with the "start debugging" option I get the following error message:

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

But it must be fine since it can compile using g++? How can such an error happen? The code I try to run is the code below:

```
#if !defined(_ARBREAVL___H_)
#define _ARBREAVL___H_
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: That's a Python error. Looks like your debugging environment in VSCode is configured incorrectly.

Comment: How would I make sure my debugging environment is configured correctly?